# Как определить зависимость для androidX?

Tags: java, android, зависимости

Скачал студию 3.2 канари вот хочу попробовать поработать с новой навигацией.

В туториале написано добавле такую зависимость

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

получаю ошибку при компиляции

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

я так понял, что теперь если начал использовать зависимость из Х версии то все зависимоти должны быть нового формата

Нашел такую ссылку по рефактору

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor

но там нет о навигации ничего.

Вопрос как сделать чтоб зависимость работала?

Мне вообще пока, что не совсем ясно как будет происходить миграция на Х версию, нужно будет найти как теперь будет выглядеть зависимость на каждую библиотеку которая используется в проекте?

**EDIT**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ezplan.navapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'

//Navigation
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha02'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0- 
alpha3'
}
```

Comment: Я пока не лез в новые компоненты, но в 3.2 есть такая фича как Jetifier она рефаткорит весь ваш код включая библиотеки и переводит все саппорт зависимости на androidx

Comment: а я наоборот лазил в 3.2) androidX b студия слишком сырые, чтобы под них разрабатывать. Потратил 3 вечера, решил вернуться на 3.1 Советую дождаться релиза.

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев я скорее всего поступлю так же

Comment: вы используете android  а не androidx namespace, каким вы образом связали navigation которая в альфе c androidx , который в альфе и оф доках да и даже в статье которую вы скинул нет в списке. Там есть условия версии gradle и min SDK, которые должны быть, для работы *.arch.navigation. От себя могу сказать что всё работает и подключается, есть внутренние баги но вполне потестить можно.

Comment: Да я понимаю, что я использую зависимость андроида, так в этом и вопрос, как ее конвертировать в зависимость Х. А статью связал таким образом, что в ней описано как форматировать зависимости в Х версию. Я видел, что ее там нет и тем самым хотел сказать, что даже в оф доках ничего об этом не сказано. Дополни вопрос своим градлом который не компилируется

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Да я понимаю, что я использую зависимость андроида, так в этом и вопрос, как ее конвертировать в зависимость Х. А статью связал таким образом, что в ней описано как форматировать зависимости в Х версию. Я видел, что ее там нет и тем самым хотел сказать, что даже в оф доках ничего об этом не сказано. Дополни вопрос своим градлом который не компилируется